# Binning multiple columns using two groupby-ed columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a *raw* table like below:

| Object | state | duration_hours | interval_hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0.06 | 0 |
| A | 1 | 0.87 | 34 |
| A | 1 | 1.5 | 80 |
| A | 2 | 18 | 0 |
| B | 1 | 7 | 0 |
| C | 1 | 0.3 | 0 |
| C | 2 | 3 | 0 |
| C | 2 | 4 | 12 |

*Tables Schema:*

1. Object: Car Object
2. State: Is it Scheduled or Unscheduled maintenance(1- Scheduled, 2- Unscheduled)
3. duration_hours: How long did the scheduled or unscheduled maintained take.
4. interval_hours: How long was the difference between first and next maintenance.(First interval for each state of object will always be 0)

**Question**

How can I:

1. Create bins *per* object and state for duration_hours and interval_hours
2. Calculate samples and probability falling in a bin *per* object and state.

**Expected Output:**

[image]
**Explanation of the output table:**

1. Size, Min, Max of the bin is configurable.
2. *Each* Object has State, Bins , Data sample and probability.
3. For *each* state, we have bins formed out of duration_hours and interval_hours.
4. *Example*: For Object A, State 1, we have:

   a. Two bins for duration_hours and Two bins for interval_hours.

   b. As there are 2 data samples between [0,1) for duration_hours, we have 2 data samples and (2/3)= 0.67 probability, similarly for interval hours, we have 2 data samples between [-1,50), we have 2 data_sample output and prob = 2/3.

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: how is the bin range set? seem to be different for each object-state

Comment: For the above example, we can take bin range for duration hours between [0,20) with an interval of 1. i.e [0,1), [1,2) ... and bin range for interval hours varies between [-1,100) with an interval of 50. (But in the real world data, the bin range/size is an input from the user). Hope it makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you want, but maybe you could use parts of it.

Provided your base dataframe is named `df`, you can start with using [`pd.cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) to bin the columns `duration_hours` and `interval_hours`:

```
bins = range(int(df.duration_hours.max()) + 2)
df["dur"] = pd.cut(df.duration_hours, bins, right=False)
bins = range(0, int(df.interval_hours.max()) + 51, 50)
df["int"] = pd.cut(df.interval_hours, bins, right=False)
```

Then [`.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) the result into a new dataframe `df_res`

```
df_res = df.melt(
    id_vars=["Object", "state"], value_vars=["dur", "int"],
    value_name="Bins", var_name="Variable", 
)
```

and [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and `.sum()` over most of it to get the `Sample` column

```
group = ["Object", "state", "Variable", "Bins"]
df_res = (
    df_res[group].assign(Sample=1).groupby(group, observed=True).sum()
)
```

and use it to build the `Prob` column (by `.groupby()`-`transform().sum()` over the first three index levels):

```
df_res["Prob"] = (
    df_res.Sample / df_res.groupby(level=[0, 1, 2]).Sample.transform('sum')
)
```

Result for

```
df = 
  Object  state  duration_hours  interval_hours
0      A      1            0.06               0
1      A      1            0.87              34
2      A      1            1.50              80
3      A      2           18.00               0
4      B      1            7.00               0
5      C      1            0.30               0
6      C      2            3.00               0
7      C      2            4.00              12
```

is

```
                                 Sample      Prob
Object state Variable Bins                        
A      1     dur      [0, 1)          2  0.666667
                      [1, 2)          1  0.333333
             int      [0, 50)         2  0.666667
                      [50, 100)       1  0.333333
       2     dur      [18, 19)        1  1.000000
             int      [0, 50)         1  1.000000
B      1     dur      [7, 8)          1  1.000000
             int      [0, 50)         1  1.000000
C      1     dur      [0, 1)          1  1.000000
             int      [0, 50)         1  1.000000
       2     dur      [3, 4)          1  0.500000
                      [4, 5)          1  0.500000
             int      [0, 50)         2  1.000000
```